# Python How to make myDcitionary['key1']['key2']=list()

Tags: python, dictionary

In python , I want to created a nested dictionary with 2 levels, the 2nd level dicts will need to have lists for values.

I am using deafultdict to make a deep dict. But how to i define the type of the second level dict to be a list.  e.g.

```
myDict[level1][level2_A]=list
myDict[level1][level2_B]=list
```

etc.

Do I use the lambda function ? I cant get it to work and know it should be a straight forward thing to do.

Thanks,

Comment: great thanks ... this is the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a nested defaultdict.

```
myDict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
```

Comment: I tried this myself but "first argument must be callable"

Comment: This is actually what i tried first but it wasn't working like I wanted.  Turned out I wasn't appending properly ! Rookie mistake.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of the following:

```
myDict[level1][level2_A] = []
myDict[level1][level2_A] = list()
```

The first option (using `[]`) is faster.